# Counter-argument to Jesus being the God-Man?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, christianity, prophet-isa, dawah

Muslims try to reason with Christians that you cannot have a God-Man, as it is impossible to be mortal and immortal at the same time or to have infinite knowledge and finite knowledge at the same time or to be needy and self-sufficient at the same time. But some Christians may say it is true that Schrödinger’s Cat is both dead and alive at the same time. What is a good counter-argument?

Answer (score 8):

> What would you say as a counter argument.

"Lakum dinukum waliyadin".

Anyone Christian who makes that argument is basing it on two fundamental misunderstandings:

- That that is how Christians claim the Godhead works (it's not)
- That Schrodinger's Cat is actually a real cat (it's not)

Arguing with someone like that, someone who doesn't even understand his own arguments while stubbornly standing behind them, is a waste of time. Just convey the message and if he chooses to continue with his fallacious beliefs, leave him to them.

Answer (score 1):

A cat is placed in a room that is separated from the outside world.

A Geiger counter which counts the amount of radioactive decay and a little bit of a radioactive element are in the room.

Within one hour, one of the atoms of the radioactive material might decay or it may not.

If the material breaks down, it will release an atomic particle, which will hit the Geiger counter, which will release poison gas, which will kill the cat.

**The question now is:** at the end of the hour, is the cat alive or dead?

Schrödinger says that according to the Copenhagen Interpretation, as long as the door is closed, the cat is dead and alive. There is no way to know until the door is opened. But by opening the door, the person is interfering with the experiment. The person and the experiment have to be described with reference to each other.

By looking at the experiment the person has influenced the experiment.

***The thought experiment was invented by Schrödinger to demonstrate the foolishness of thinking about quantum states for large objects.***

And yet your Christian friend(s) used it for a non-quantum object (Jesus). Also note that **God is beyond the realm of both quantum and classical physics**.

Comment: A cat is also a non-quantum object...

Comment: Also see this [physics question and answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/320547/definition-of-the-words-macroscopic-classical-object-vs-quantum-object). Every object in the physical universe is governed by quantum mechanics, but [most of the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscopic_quantum_phenomena) we can ignore quantum effects and use the classical approach that becomes just an approximation and increasingly inaccurate as you approach smaller length and time scales, seeing quantum confinement effects such as those in quantum materials, my topic of research experience.

Comment: Schrodinger's cat is another example of where quantum mechanical effects are applicable to large objects or can be seen at large length and time scales. Also, God being "beyond the realm of both quantum and classical physics" isn't really a counter-argument to what seems to mostly be an [argument from analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_analogy).

Answer (score 0):

We agree about that Schrodinger’s cat as part of theory in Science.

Science is built by assumptions.
And those assumptions are being corrected time by time when the more accurate ones discovered.

> However, God is free from that error.

For example, the methodology of psychology named “Behavioral” used to be accepted as science as it is measurable.

However, then comes the “cognitive psychology” as scientists did not agree that everything that matters are able to be measured.

So, do not worship science, blindly.
Science is useful as a tool for discovery.

> Associating God with science which is still ambiguous is not relevant (*the cat is not a real cat

then, I also agree with the answer from Goldpseudo

> Lakum diinukum waliyadiin (لَكُمْ دِينُكُمْ وَلِيَ دِينِ)
>
> They have ear but could not hear, they have eyes but could not see. Because they have been so arrogant when the truth is crystal clear. So Allah locks their heart.

Answer (score -2):

God is not a Schrödinger’sGod. If God was a Schrödinger’sGod then God would have been Dead and Alive, Nescient and Omniscient at the same time.Additionally it is a Contradiction and God is beyond Schrödinger’s problem. This problem is Absolutely Impossible upon God.